# Tensorflow / CUDA: GPU not detected

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have two Windows 11 laptops with NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 GPUs, which I want to run Tensorflow on.

If that matters, both laptops are Lenovo Legion 5 laptops with "GPU Working Mode" set to "Hybrid-Auto Mode".

The first laptop has the following setup:

```
Python     3.10.7
Tensorflow 2.9.1
CUDA       11.2.0
cuDNN      8.1.1

CPU        AMD Ryzen 7 6800H
GPU0       NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060
GPU1       AMD Radeon Graphics
```

The second laptop has the following setup:

```
Python     3.10.9 Virtual Environment
Tensorflow 2.11.0
CUDA       11.2.2
cuDNN      8.1.1

CPU        Intel Core i7 12th Gen 12700H
GPU0       Intel Iris Xe
GPU1       NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060
```

CUDA and cuDNN were installed as per this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHWkvEcDBO0 (except for the conda part).

On the first laptop, everything works fine. But on the second, when executing `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`, I get an empty list.

I have tried to set the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` variable to `"0"` as some people mentioned on other posts, but it didn't work.

I also tried the same as the second laptop on a third one, and got the same problem.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually the problem is that you are using Windows, TensorFlow 2.11 and newer versions do not have anymore native support for GPUs on Windows, see from the TensorFlow [website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip):

> Caution: TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you will need to install TensorFlow in WSL2, or install tensorflow-cpu and, optionally, try the TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin

From TensorFlow 2.11 onwards, the only way to get GPU support on Windows is to use [WSL2](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-wsl2).

Comment: This is correct. Have you found any explanation for why TensforFlow stopped supporting GPU's on windows native?

Comment: @Dylan Warburg I'm also interested.

The comment is over a year old, is it still the case that if you want to use your GPUs to accelerate TF-based computing, then you have to either use WSL2 or downgrade to TF 2.9?

Comment: Will this impact performance for future versions of TF on windows? Now that we have to install/run additional middleware to fix the issue?